# DataSnap Server complaining about Server Method not existing ...Delphi 2010 DataSnap

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, datasnap

I have a DataSnap Server with a Server method like this:

```
function TServerMethods1.selectFalzUser(Usuario: string) : TDataSet;
```

Now, on the DataSnap Client using TSQLServerMethod, I successfully connect to the server in Design Mode, pull server's methods list ... select 'selectFalzUser'... and I can succesfully see my params, both Usuario as INput, and the output TDataset Param... when a try to set my SqlServerMethod Active ... I get the following error:

> Error Remote error: TServerMethods1.selectFalzUserwhereUsuario method
>   not found in the server method list.

Why Delphi is appending 'whereUsuario' string to the method name? Obviously  TServerMethods1.selectFalzUserwhereUsuario does not exist.

Regards

zaguerino.

Comment: TDataSet is not a type you can return in a DataSnap remote function call.  Un saludo.!

Comment: Hi , I was reading Bob Swart's White Paper: "Delphi 2010 DataSnap: Your data where you want it, how you want it", where it shows a Server Method named:


function TServerMethods1.GetEmployees: TDataSet;


What would be the correct type to return rows in a server method? 

Regards

Zaguerinho

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it is hard to say why it isn't reporting the method name correctly.  However, it doesn't sound like you are using DataSnap quite right.  Here is what I have done successfully for several projects:

You must include `{$METHODINFO ON}` before the `TServerMethods` class definition and `{$METHODINFO OFF}` after the class definition in the DataSnap server.  Then compile and run your DS server.

On the client side, add a `TSQLConnection` component and set its properties to connect to your listing DS server.  Then right click the `TSQLConnection` and select `Generate DataSnap client classes`.  Save this as something like `ProxyMethods.pas` and include it in your client project.  Then you can access the `ProxyMethods` class to call any of the published `TServerMethods` in the server.

Also, returning `TDataSet` won't work with the approach I described because `TDataSet` is not a marshallable datatype, however OleVariant is.  I have had good success with returning a `TClientDataSet.Data`, and then on the client side I can assign this directly the `Data` property of a client-side `TClientDataSet`.

Comment: Thank you, I added the directives but still same error. I had to create a server method exactly as the name it was complaining then call the original method name inside very weird and it worked, but doesn't seem right.

Comment: I agree, that doesn't seem right.  You might revise your question and describe the process you used (in detail) to create both the client and the server.  There are several DataSnap gurus on SO that could help identify the issue.